# How do we know that this set is measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathbb{A},P)$ be a probability triple and $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables. $X_n$ converges almost surely if and only if $Prob(w \in \Omega:X_n(w) \to X(w) \ as \ n \ \to  \ \infty )=1$.

How do we know that this set is measurable?

Thanks.

Christian

Comment: The assumption of measurability of that set is part of the definition.

Comment: @JonasMeyer I do not understand your comment. What are you alluding to?

Comment: @did: Looking at it now, probably I misunderstood.  It looked like the first part is a statement of the definition of almost sure convergence to me.  If that had been the case, the appearance of the statement  "$Prob(w \in \Omega:X_n(w) \to X(w) \ as \ n \ \to  \ \infty )=1$" would presume that $\{w \in \Omega:X_n(w) \to X(w) \ as \ n \ \to  \ \infty \}$ is something at which "$Prob$" can be meaningfully evaluated, i.e., is measurable.  Apparently I am confused.

Comment: You're not confused (Although I sense a hint of sarcasm).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If every $X_n$ is measurable and the event $[X_n\to X]$ is almost sure, then $X$ is measurable${}^*$ since
$$
[X_n\to X]\cap[X\leqslant x]=[X_n\to X]\cap\bigcap_{n\geqslant1}\bigcap_{k\geqslant1}\bigcup_{i\geqslant k}[X_i\leqslant x+\tfrac1n].
$$
If $X$ and every $X_n$ are measurable, the set $[X_n\to X]$ is measurable since 
$$
[X_n\to X]=\bigcap_{n\geqslant1}\bigcup_{k\geqslant1}\bigcap_{i\geqslant k}\,[|X_i-X|\leqslant\tfrac1n].
$$
**Edit:** ${}^*$ This assumes that the sigma-algebra $\mathcal A$ is complete, that is, that $\mathcal A$ contains every subset of every $A$ in $\mathcal A$ such that $\mathbb P(A)=0$. Otherwise, assume that $[X_n\to X]=\Omega$.

Comment: Can you please tell me why the set within the unions and intersections is measurable...?

Comment: If $Y:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is a measurable function, then every subset $[Y\leqslant y]=Y^{-1}((-\infty,y])$ of $\Omega$ is measurable because each subset $(-\infty,y]$ of $\mathbb R$ is.

Comment: That's the definition of measurability of Y. But why is the absolute value of the difference of two RVs measurable?

Comment: Because this is a measurable function of the measurable pair $(X_i,X)$. (By the way, which textbook are you following?)

Comment: I only recently started studying measure-theory... Foundations of Modern Probability by Kallenberg. Don't you have to prove that it is a measurable function?

Comment: Surely you might have heard that $(x',x)\mapsto x'-x$ is measurable.

Comment: That's not obvious to me. Again, I just started studying measure theory.

Comment: So I had guessed. Hint: this function is continuous.

Comment: Continuous functions are measurable...